# Error in installing the package wordcloud in python

Tags: python, cmd, word-cloud

I have a problem regarding installing wordcloud. I tried downloading it through Python using `pip install wordcloud`, and this is what the output is:

```
C:\Users\y>pip install wordcloud
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import Distribution
  File "C:\Users\y\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
```

If anyone could help me I would be extremely grateful! :) I have a version of Python 3.12

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `pip` or use an older version of Python. This [seems to be a known and fixed issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11501).

Comment: I upgraded pip and I previously used Python 3.7 and I still get the error message.